# Is there any way to replicate our AWS EC2 instances without using Auto-scaling option?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Thanks in advance....

we have RDS replication with multi-AZ option. Is there any way to replicate our AWS EC2 instances without using Auto-scaling option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the EC2 console listing running instances, select the instance you want to replicate and under Actions click Launch More Like This.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launch-more-like-this.html

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, configure your EC2 instance exactly the way you want it to be. Stop the instance and create an AMI of this instance. Then launch as many EC2 instances as you want using the AMI. Each EC2 instance will be almost identical. There will be differences due to licensing, IP addressing, instance ID, etc.

This is the same technique that you would use with Auto Scaling Groups (e.g. new instances are launched from a specific AMI).

Another option is to use Launch More Like This from the EC2 Console. However, this feature does not clone your instance, only replicates some configuration details.